# Internal dns server with bind + centos

Tags: dns, centos, bind

I'm running bind 9 in a CentOS 6.3 machine and trying do setup and internal DNS server.

I'm really new to this and need to set this up for my company, the guy responsible for this just quited and I'm my own for a while. Thanks in advance.

I've tried a few tutorials and so far this is what I have:

named.conf file

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.24; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
          statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
          memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24;};
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
 };

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
   type hint;
   file "named.ca";
};

zone "local.logits.me" IN {
     type master;
     file "fwd.local.logits.me";
     allow-update {none;};
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "rev.local.logits.me";
    allow-update {none;};
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

fwd.local.logits.me file

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA web.local.logits.me. root.local.logits.me. (
     2013102113 ; serial
     3600       ; refresh
     1800       ; retry
     604800     ; expire
     86400      ; minimum Time to Lie (TTL)
)
@     IN      NS            web.local.logits.me.
@     IN      A             192.168.0.24
web   IN      A             192.168.0.24
```

rev.local.logits.me file

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN    SOA   web.local.logits.me. root.local.logits.me. (
    2013102113 ; serial
    3600       ; refresh
    1800       ; retry
    604800     ; expire
    86400      ; minimum time to live (TTL)
)
@       IN      NS        web.local.logits.me.
@       IN      PTR       local.logits.me.
web     IN      A         192.168.0.24
24      IN      PTR       web.local.logits.me.
```

And this is what I get when I try nslookup

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup local.logits.me
Server:         192.168.0.24
Address:        192.168.0.24#53

** server can't find local.logits.me: NXDOMAIN

[root@localhost ~]# nslookup web.local.logits.me
Server:         192.168.0.24
Address:        192.168.0.24#53

** server can't find web.local.logits.me: NXDOMAIN

[root@localhost ~]# nslookup 192.168.0.24
Server:         192.168.0.24
Address:        192.168.0.24#53

** server can't find 24.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your configuration works perfectly fine on my vanilla CentOS 6.3 test instance. Have you done `service named reload`?

Comment: I did "service named restart". Reloading fails. All I get is:
Reloading named-sdb:                                       [FAILED]
/var/log/messages gives me: Oct 23 14:49:24 localhost named-sdb[14055]: error (network unreachable) resolvin                                                                                        g 'safebrowsing.clients.google.com/AAAA/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Someone (either me or the guy before me) put the files on the wrong folder.

So I was editing files on '/' instead of the named root path given in '/etc/sysconfig/named'.
The root path is '/var/named/chroot', so I moved the config files there and everything works fine.